# Current $i(t)$ in a "charged" inductor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electronics, inductance

I have this circuit:

[image]

with $$v(t)=-30e^{-5t}$$
and inductor 1 has a initial current of 3A and inductor 2 of -5A.

My roommate and I are disagreeing about the current i(t).
Since it is $$i(t)=1/L \int v(t) dt +i(0) $$ L being a parallel association (48mH),
the correct current will be $$ i(t)=125e^{-5t}-2A$$ or $$ i(t)=125e^{-5t}-127A$$

Our doubt is, the initial current in a inductor is the i(0), that appears in the equation or i need to do $$ i(0)=-2=125e^{-5*0}+i_0$$ and solve for i0?

Comment: Since the two inductors have different initial conditions, just solve the integral equation for each one separately and then sum at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two inductors are in parallel

$$
v(t) = L_1\frac{{\rm d}i_1}{{\rm d} t} = L_2\frac{{\rm d}i_2}{{\rm d} t} 
$$

The solution to each equation is

$$
i_\alpha(t) = i_\alpha(0) + \frac{6}{L_\alpha}[e^{-5t} - 1]
$$

so that the current $i(t)$ is simply

$$
i(t) = i_1(t) + i_2(t) = [i_1(0) + i_2(0)] + 6\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{L_1} + \frac{1}{L_2}\right)}_{1/L}[e^{-5t} - 1]
$$

Comment: $$
i_\alpha(t) = i_\alpha(0) + \frac{6}{L_\alpha}[e^{-5t} - 1]
$$
Why e^(-5t) -1? The -1 comes from solving the integral?

Comment: @renandame Right, from solving the integral. Try to derive 

$$
L_\alpha \frac{{\rm d}i_\alpha}{{\rm d}t} = v(t)
$$